# React + Webpack: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number

Tags: reactjs

Why am I getting that error in the console of the chrome ?

My code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hello React</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root">
<!-- my app renders here -->
</div>

    <script src="../react-15.3.1/build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../react-15.3.1/build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import SalutaMondo from './salutamondo';

var UnaProva = React.createClass({

   render: function(){
      return (
         <div>
            <SalutaMondo/>
            <div>Ciao Emiliano</div>
         </div>
      );
   },

});

ReactDOM.render(<UnaProva />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

salutamondo.js

```
    var SalutaMondo = React.createClass({
       render: function(){
          return (
             <h1>Hello World</h1>
          );

       }


    });

module.export = SalutaMondo;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: [ './src/salutamondo.js', './src/main.js' ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,        
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two entry points? Why are you using `module.exports` from one place and `import` from another? Shouldn't you just use `export var SalutaMondo = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webpack config, you're using the `babel-loader`. This implies that you're using ES6 style modules. In `salutamondo.js`, you're using CommonJS style modules. As a result, the `babel-loader` isn't picking up the module. Can you try:

```
export default SalutaMondo;
```

instead of:

```
module.export = SalutaMondo;
```

Comment: So should I extend React.Component instead of using React.createClass too ?

Comment: You can do either, it depends on what sort of style you prefer, I typically use React.createClass since it doesn't pull in extra bloat from babel. From the docs: "If you don't use ES6 yet, you may use the React.createClass helper instead." https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @xRobot This page contains more info about the differences between using React with and without ES6: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to `salutamondo.js` using CommonJS module format, while `main.js` is using ECMAScript module. I recommend keeping everything in ECMAScript modules:

```
    var SalutaMondo = React.createClass({
       render: function(){
          return (
             <h1>Hello World</h1>
          );

       }


    });

export default SalutaMondo;
```

Comment: So should I extend React.Component instead of using React.createClass too ?

Comment: @xRobot yes, preferably. `createClass` is going to be [deprecated in React 15.5](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8854).